# Jquery Handler Function + requireJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I created a requireJs module where I already put all the functions:

```
define(['Scrollbar','module'],function(Scrollbar,module){
     return{
        init:function(){
            //CODE
        },
        manageScroll:function(){
            //CODE
        },
        manageResize:function(){
            //CODE
        },
        transform(){
            //CODE
        }
    }

});
```

In the init section I defined a handler Jquery on the resize  which recall a function on this object

I tryied in this way:

```
init:function(){
    this.transform();
    jQuery(window).resize(this.manageResize());
},
```

But it dosn’t work, the only solution I found is this one here below, but it doens’t work on IE.

```
init:function(){
    this.transform();
    jQuery(window).resize(()=>this.manageResize());
},
```

Do you have any suggestion or better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a callback to `jQuery(window).resize()`. Something like this:

```
init:function(){
    this.transform();
    jQuery(window).resize(this.manageResize.bind(this));
},
```

We need to use `.bind(this)` otherwise `this` will have the value `undefined` inside of the `manageResize` method. (See [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for details of how it works.)

In the first attempt, you're passing the *return value* of `this.manageResize()`. Unless you are returning a callback, this cannot work.

In your second attempt which does not work in IE, you are using an arrow function, which is simply not supported by any of the IE browsers.

Comment: but now i have error because manageResize call another function this.transform :'(

Comment: Sorry. I managed to forget the `bind` bit. You need to use `.bind(this)` to make sure that `this` in bound to the proper value when `this.manageResize` is called.